# Qt6 fails to antialias custom font

Tags: c++, qt

When I use a `QLabel` with a custom font (Open Sans), I get this ugly result:

[image]

You can see the pixelation around the edges of the letters. Here's a high quality render of the same `.otf` font file (via Chrome):

[image]

Side by side comparison:

[image]

And close up:

[image]

Current code:

```cpp
int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/font/OpenSans/700.otf");
QString family = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0);
QFont* OpenSans700 = new QFont(family);
OpenSans700->setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias); // doesn't appear to do anything

QLabel* label = new QLabel("Welcome, Guest");
label->setFont(OpenSans700);
```

How do I improve the rendering quality so that it doesn't look pixelated? I've scoured the web for possible solutions, but it nothing is working.

- It's not an issue with my `.otf` file, Chrome is able to render it perfectly.
- I am using qt 6.2.2
- I am on Windows 11
- My screen dimensions are 2560x1440
- The font is rendered at 24px (other sizes have no effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Font Hinting](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfont.html#HintingPreference-enum) is used to "improve legibility on displays where it might be warranted by the density of pixels". It does not, however, look pretty.

Disable it:

```cpp
OpenSans700->setHintingPreference(QFont::HintingPreference::PreferNoHinting)
```

[image]